# The objects on the second form are null JavaFX

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx

I am having trouble figuring out why the variables are null even though I loaded the second FXML form into the GUI. The second fxml form contains a TabPane, **theImageDisplayer**, and two ImageViews, **editedImage** and **orignialImage**. None of the variables from the second FXML initialize and it is stopping my GUI from performing certain actions such as "importing an image from the computer."

Here is my code:

```
private void initializeRootLayout() {
    Scene scene = new Scene(this.rootLayout);
    this.primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    this.primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    this.primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    this.initializeImageView(); <-- Initializes the Tab Layout
    -->this.initializePictureController();<--  Initializes my controller PictureController
    this.primaryStage.show();
}

private void initializeImageView() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/edu/westga/SignboardProjectXXX/view/PictureView.fxml"));
        this.tabs = (TabPane) loader.load();<-- Initializes the TabLayout with the null variables

        this.rootLayout.setCenter(this.tabs); <-- Adds the Tab Layout to the root layout
```

---

Here is where my controller, PictureContoller, crashes:

public class PictureController {

```
@FXML
---->private TabPane theImageDisplayer;<---- The variable is located here.

@FXML
private ListView<Picture> imageHistoryList;

//Textfields:
@FXML
private TextField imageDimensions;

@FXML
private TextField imageLinkBox;

@FXML
private TextField imageName;

// Labels:
@FXML
private Label pixelsPerHeight;

@FXML
private Label resizePercentage;

@FXML
private Label zoomEditedImagePercentage;

@FXML
private Label pixelsPerLength;

@FXML
private Label pixelsPerWidth;

// Check-box Button:
@FXML
private CheckBox replaceOriginalImage;

@FXML
private CheckBox eraseHistoryOnImageChange;

// Sliders:
@FXML
private Slider imageResizeSlider;

@FXML
private Slider zoomEditedImageSlider;

@FXML
private Slider pixelsPerHeightSlider;

@FXML
private Slider pixelsPerWidthSlider;

// Accordion Menu:
@FXML
private Accordion theMainMenu;

// Toggle Buttons:
@FXML
private ToggleGroup fileType;

@FXML
private ToggleButton toggleEditedImageVisibility;

// Buttons:
@FXML
private Button restoreImageButton;

@FXML
private Button downloadImageButton;

@FXML
private Button uploadImageButton;

// Radio Buttons:
@FXML
private RadioButton pngRadioButton;

@FXML
private RadioButton gifRadioButton;

@FXML
private RadioButton jpegRadioButton;

@FXML
private RadioButton jpgRadioButton;

// Image Displays:
@FXML
private ImageView originalImage;

@FXML
private ImageView historyPreviewImage;

@FXML
private ImageView editedImage;

// Instance Variables:
private UploadDownloadController loadSaveController;
private ImageFilterController filterController;
private ObservableList<Picture> imageHistory;
private String imageSaveExtension;
private Picture originalPic;
private Picture currEditedPic;
private PictureIO io;
private ArrayList<RadioButton> saveTypesExtension;

private static final int ORIGINAL_IMAGE_TAB = 0;
private static final int EDITED_IMAGE_TAB = 1;

public void initialize() {
    this.io = new PictureIO();
    this.loadSaveController = new UploadDownloadController();
    this.originalPic = new Picture("Default", 100, 100);
    this.currEditedPic = new Picture("Default", 100, 100);
    this.saveTypesExtension = this.buildTemporarySaveTypeList();
}

@FXML
private void toggleSelection(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("hello6");
}

@FXML
private void changeRadioButtonSetValue(ActionEvent event) {
    this.setImageSaveExtentionValue();
}

@FXML
private void changePixelWidthPerSquare(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setValueOfLabel(this.pixelsPerWidthSlider, this.pixelsPerWidth);
}

@FXML
private void changePixelHeightPerSquare(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setValueOfLabel(this.pixelsPerHeightSlider, this.pixelsPerHeight);
}

@FXML
private void changeImageSize(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setValueOfLabel(this.imageResizeSlider, this.resizePercentage);
}

@FXML
private void changeEditedZoomLevel(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setValueOfLabel(this.zoomEditedImageSlider, this.zoomEditedImagePercentage);
}

@FXML
private void toggleEditedImageVisibility(ActionEvent event) {
    this.toggleVisibility(this.editedImage);
}

@FXML
private void uploadImageFromComputer(ActionEvent event) {
    this.loadFromComputer();
    this.selectTab(EDITED_IMAGE_TAB);
}

@FXML
private void downloadImageFromWeb(ActionEvent event) {
    this.getImageFromWeb();
    this.selectTab(EDITED_IMAGE_TAB);

    System.out
            .println("Warn users a better way. This does not go away after a few seconds.");
}

private void selectTab(final int theTab) {
    SingleSelectionModel<Tab> sinlgeSelection = this.theImageDisplayer.getSelectionModel();
    sinlgeSelection.select(theTab);
}

@FXML
private void displayImageInformation(MouseEvent event) {
    this.getInformationFromPicture();
}

@FXML
private void restoreSelectedImage(ActionEvent event) {
    this.revertImageWithPrevImage();
}

@FXML
private void resizeImage(ActionEvent event) {
    double realPercentageValue = this.io.changeStringToNumber(this.resizePercentage.getText()) / 100.0;
    System.out.println("Result: " + realPercentageValue);
    this.filterController = new ImageFilterController(this.currEditedPic);
    Picture picture = this.filterController.resizedPicture(realPercentageValue);
    this.changeEditedImage(picture);
    this.io.convertPictureToImage(picture);
}

// private void warnUser() {
// Tooltip warningToUser = new
// Tooltip("Please enter value in the text area above.");
// Tooltip.install(this.downloadImageButton, warningToUser);
// warningToUser.show(this.downloadImageButton, 0, 0);
// //TODO make tooltip work
// }

private void setImageSaveExtentionValue() {
    for (RadioButton selectedRadioButton : this.saveTypesExtension) {
        if (selectedRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            this.imageSaveExtension = selectedRadioButton.getText();
        }
    }
}

private ArrayList<RadioButton> buildTemporarySaveTypeList() {
    ArrayList<RadioButton> imagesaveTypes = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    imagesaveTypes.add(this.gifRadioButton);
    imagesaveTypes.add(this.pngRadioButton);
    imagesaveTypes.add(this.jpgRadioButton);
    imagesaveTypes.add(this.jpegRadioButton);
    return imagesaveTypes;
}

private void setValueOfLabel(Slider theSlider, Label theLabel) {
    theSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue,
                        Boolean wasChanging, Boolean changing) {
                    if (wasChanging || changing) {
                        theLabel.setText((int) theSlider.getValue() + "");
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void toggleVisibility(Node targetObject) {
    boolean currVisibility = targetObject.isVisible();
    targetObject.setVisible(!currVisibility);
}

private void revertImageWithPrevImage() {
    try {
        Picture prevPicture = this.io.convertImageToPicture(this.editedImage);
        this.imageHistory.add(prevPicture);
        Picture restoredPicture = this.imageHistoryList.getSelectionModel()
                .getSelectedItem();
        this.currEditedPic = new Picture(restoredPicture.getName(), restoredPicture.getImage());
        Image theImage = this.io.convertPictureToImage(restoredPicture);
        this.editedImage.setImage(theImage);
    } catch (Exception nullImage) {
        nullImage.getMessage();
    }
}

private void refreshHistoryList(Picture picture) {
    this.imageHistory = this.imageHistoryList.getItems();
    this.imageHistory.add(picture);
    this.imageHistoryList.setItems(this.imageHistory);
}

private void getInformationFromPicture() {
    Picture picture = this.imageHistoryList.getSelectionModel()
            .getSelectedItem();
    if (picture != null) {
        this.imageName.setText(picture.getName());
        this.imageDimensions.setText(picture.getWidth() + " x "
                + picture.getHeight());
        Image theImage = this.io.convertPictureToImage(picture);
        this.historyPreviewImage.setImage(theImage);
    }

}

private void loadFromComputer() {
    Picture picture = this.loadSaveController.uploadImage();
    this.changeAndStoreImage(picture);
}

private void getImageFromWeb() {
    String imageWebLink = this.imageLinkBox.getText();
    if (!imageWebLink.equals("")) {
        Picture picture = this.loadSaveController
                .downloadImage(this.imageLinkBox.getText());
        this.changeAndStoreImage(picture);
        this.imageLinkBox.clear();
    }
}

private void changeAndStoreImage(Picture picture) {
    if (!picture.getName().equals("No Image")) {
        this.changeEditedImage(picture);
        this.setOriginalImage(picture);
        this.refreshHistoryList(picture);
    }
}

private void changeEditedImage(Picture picture) {
    this.currEditedPic = new Picture(picture.getName(), picture.getImage());
    ------>this.theImageDisplayer.getTabs().get(1).setDisable(false);<------ It crashes here*
    Image theImage = this.io.convertPictureToImage(picture);
    this.editedImage.setImage(theImage);
    this.adjustImageSize(this.editedImage);
}

private void setOriginalImage(Picture picture) {
    this.originalPic = new Picture(picture.getName(), picture.getImage());
    Image theImage = this.io.convertPictureToImage(picture);
    this.originalImage.setImage(theImage);
    this.adjustImageSize(this.originalImage);
}

private void adjustImageSize(ImageView image) {
    this.adjustWidth(image);
    this.adjustHeight(image);
}

private void adjustHeight(ImageView image) {
    double imageDisplayHeight = this.theImageDisplayer.getHeight();
    double theImageHeight = image.getImage().getHeight();
    if (imageDisplayHeight < theImageHeight) {
        image.setFitWidth(imageDisplayHeight);
    }
}

private void adjustWidth(ImageView image) {
    double theImageWidth = image.getImage().getWidth();
    double imageDisplayWidth = this.theImageDisplayer.getWidth();
    if (imageDisplayWidth < theImageWidth) {
        image.setFitWidth(imageDisplayWidth);
    }
}
```

}

---

Here is the second FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>


<TabPane fx:id="theImageDisplayer" prefHeight="643.0" prefWidth="614.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="edu.westga.SignboardProjectMichaelMorguarge.view.PictureController">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Original Image">
      <content>
            <Pane prefHeight="614.0" prefWidth="607.0">
               <children>
                  <ScrollPane prefHeight="614.0" prefViewportHeight="180.0" prefViewportWidth="200.0" prefWidth="607.0">
                     <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="612.0" prefWidth="605.0">
                           <children>
                              <ImageView fx:id="originalImage" fitHeight="588.0" fitWidth="477.0" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="271.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="271.00199127197266" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="64.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="64.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="271.0">
                                 <effect>
                                    <DropShadow />
                                 </effect>
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../../../../../Welcome.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </ScrollPane>
               </children>
            </Pane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab disable="true" text="Signboard">
      <content>
            <Pane>
               <children>
                  <ScrollPane prefHeight="614.0" prefViewportHeight="180.0" prefViewportWidth="200.0" prefWidth="607.0">
                     <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="612.0" prefWidth="605.0">
                           <children>
                              <ImageView fx:id="editedImage" fitHeight="588.0" fitWidth="477.0" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="12.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="64.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="64.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="12.0">
                                 <effect>
                                    <DropShadow />
                                 </effect>
                              </ImageView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </content>
                  </ScrollPane>
               </children>
            </Pane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

---

**If there is anymore information you want to know, yell at me... I will be watching this and am up for suggestions.**

Comment: You're referring to your variables with the `this` identifier, so i'm assuming they're static. I believe you can't have JavaFX variables as static; just leave them as `@FXML private TabPane theImageDisplayer;`

Comment: Can you post all of `PictureContoller.java` code ?

Comment: I posted the  code for the PictureController. Anything else let me know.